# Que tecnologia há por traz das máquinas virtuais?

Tags: compilação, desempenho

Além de *Java* e do ambiente *.NET* diversos outros ambientes como *Python*, *Ruby*, *Lua*, etc interpretam **bytecodes**. Logo nas primeiras versões *Java* deixava a desejar em termos de performance, mas o ambiente evoluiu muito e hoje possui uma boa performance...

Claro que a tecnologia **JIT** ajuda muito, e também sei que existem diferenças conceituais entre as **VMs** (por exemplo a **VM Lua** é baseada em registradores, e não em pilha, como as demais), mas é apenas isso? Ou perguntando de outra forma... teoricamente utilizando a tecnologia **JIT**, todas as **VMs** poderiam ter performance semelhante?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **TL;DR - não**, o JIT é um fator de peso, mas não é o único que influencia a performance de um programa baseado numa VM.

## Fundamentos

Em geral, qualquer programa de computador passa por diversas etapas de transformação desde o código fonte até o código de máquina. O próprio código de máquina costuma também sofrer transformações - essa feita pela própria CPU - de modo a converter suas instruções para [microcódigo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode). Somente este é executado de fato. Ainda assim, não é possível se programar diretamente em microcódigo, pois o que o processador espera - o tipo de entrada que ele consegue tratar - é um programa em linguagem de máquina, com seu formato e características próprias.

O que define o que pode ter no código de máquina é o que chamamos de **arquitetura do computador**. Nas máquinas mais simples - aquelas sem microinstruções - a arquitetura descreve uma máquina real, com componentes que existem de fato, na forma física. Nas demais, pode-se dizer que ela descreve uma máquina virtual (ainda que essa expressão não seja comumente usada nesse contexto). Pois o que existe de fato é uma máquina capaz de se comportar como descrito na arquitetura, ainda que por baixo dos panos ela esteja fazendo coisas diferentes.

O [x86](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) é uma arquitetura. O [System/360](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360) também. Ambas empregam microcódigo, o que significa que cada instrução em código de máquina primeiro é convertida em microinstruções e depois executadas pela CPU. Isso permite que um mesmo programa funcione em várias gerações sucessivas de computadores (ex.: 386, 486, 586/Pentium, Core Duo), que longe de serem o mesmo tipo de máquina, implementam características cada vez mais avançadas (pipeline, superescalar, paralelismo...).

A **Maquina Virtual Java** é simplesmente mais uma arquitetura: ela define um conjunto de instruções, um modelo de processamento, etc, tal como se estivesse descrevendo uma máquina real. A diferença é que ela foi concebida pensando-se primariamente em ser implementada através de software, ainda que em princípio seja perfeitamente possível implementá-la em hardware - ver [**picoJava**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PicoJava).

## Tradução e Performance

Como já foi dito, o que executa de fato no processador não é o código de máquina, mas o microcódigo. Por essa razão, o mesmo código de máquina pode ter performance radicalmente diferente quando transportado da máquina A pra máquina B, dentro da mesma arquitetura. Historicamente, quando se usava muito o Código de Montagem (Assembly), havia a possibilidade - ao menos teórica - de que uma otimização que explorasse uma característica particular de um processador saísse pela culatra, ao mudar de processador e perceber-se que o desempenho era ainda pior do que se tal otimização não tivesse sido feita.

De todo modo, esse é um problema do projetista do hardware, não do programador - garantir que o código de máquina se traduza em um microcódigo correto e eficiente. Entretanto, as demais etapas de transformação que levam do código fonte até o código de máquina, essas sim são feitas em software - e podem levar a um desempenho melhor ou pior dependendo da qualidade dessa transformação.

Um dos principais desafios de quem projeta um compilador é pegar um programa na linguagem A (de mais alto nível) e traduzi-lo em um programa equivalente na linguagem B (de mais baixo nível), de modo que o mesmo saia correto e eficiente. Técnicas de otimização mais sofisticadas podem produzir resultados melhores, mas provavelmente tornarão a compilação em si mais lenta. Isso coloca um limite no que um compilador JIT é capaz de fazer: pois o tempo de execução de um programa JITado inclui não só sua execução mas também sua transformação em código de máquina. A princípio, então, eu diria que um progrma JITado jamais chegará a ter uma performance tão boa quanto um programa pré-compilado.

Por outro lado, o ganho em performance com otimizações não é sempre proporcional ao tempo gasto fazendo as mesmas. Um compilador que demore 10 minutos pra compilar não produzirá um código 10x mais rápido que outro que demore 1 minuto. A diferença marginal de desempenho se torna cada vez menor à medida que as otimizações são feitas, até chegar ao ponto que não compensa sofisticar mais - não só pelo tempo a mais de compilação, como pelo tempo a mais projetando, implementando e testando o compilador.

Some-se isso à [Lei de Moore](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Moore), e temos que o overhead de um compilador JIT se torna mais e mais insignificante à medida que o tempo passa, até que eventualmente chegaremos ao ponto de não haver diferença perceptível na performance de programas pré-compilados e JITados (ainda não estamos lá, entretanto...)

(Outro fato que vale a pena mencionar, ainda que não diretamente perguntado, é que a compilação JIT oferece seus próprios benefícios em relação à compilação tradicional, por exemplo a [Otimização Adaptativa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_optimization) e a [Recompilação Dinâmica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_recompilation); por essa razão, em certas situações a performance de um programa JITado pode ser até **superior** a de um programa pré-compilado)

## Arquiteturas de Pilhas vs. Registradores

Como já foi dito, os programas passam por uma série de transformações até chegar em código de máquina. Algumas dessas transformações pegam uma instrução complexa e a quebram em instruções menores (ex.: se a arquitetura-alvo for [RISC](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC)), enquanto outras pegam várias instruções pequenas e as combinam em uma instrução só. Não posso falar sobre o CLR ou a VM Lua (ou o LLVM, o Parrot, o Squeak...), mas lembro de já ter lido que algo desse tipo ocorre com os bytecodes da JVM.

Se o resultado final serão programas com performance semelhante, isso não sei dizer. Minha intuição diz que não: se a VM é baseada em pilha, ela perde a chance de se aproveitar ao máximo dos registradores da máquina real (um queixa comum em relação ao Java é a impossibilidade de um método retornar mais de um valor - algo que seria trivial de se fazer com registradores, mas impraticável sem quebrar a compatibilidade da JVM). Conversamente, se a VM usa registradores mas a máquina real não (ex.: Lua rodando no picoJava) - ou mesmo se o número de registradores definidos pela VM excede aqueles suportados pela máquina física - é possível que um conjunto simples de instruções bytecode acabem por se tornar um conjunto bem maior e menos eficiente de instruções no código de máquina.

Veja bem que isso independe da VM ser JITada ou não; até mesmo um compilador estático teria dificuldades de se produzir código eficiente ao fazer a tradução entre arquiteturas radicalmente diferentes. (De novo, essa é minha interpretação pessoal dos fatos - sem acesso a uma pessoa com conhecimentos práticos na implementação de VMs não dá pra saber se esses obstáculos são fáceis ou difíceis de se transpor)