# C# é uma linguagem compilada ou interpretada?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem

Estou iniciando os estudos em C#, e estou com dúvida se a linguagem é compilada ou interpretada?

Minha dúvida surge porque ouvi em uma palestra dizer que é compilada, e outros dizendo que é interpretada.

Comment: C# linguagem compilada

Comment: Eu também quero saber... Acabei de ver no google (Wikipedia) eles falando que é **Interpretada**, mas o cara da palestra falou que é **compilada**

Comment: @WallaceMaxters cite a fonte que diz sobre a interpretação.

Comment: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp

Comment: @WallaceMaxters nossa a WIkepdia em portugês está cheia de erros. E o pior que você tenta resolver, tem sempre um cara que acha que é dono do verbete e não deixa mexer. Por isso que eu digo que tem que olhar tudo em inglês mesmo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29

Comment: @bigown Cansei de discutir com esses caras da WP em portugues, nem mexo mais lá. Já tive varios bugfixes revertidos pra versão com bug. Tem um mané lá que eu não vou dizer o nome, mas é bem famoso na versão em português que quer ele mesmo mexer. Voce tem que ficar "negociando" a postagem e o cara faz questao de aparecer em todas.

Comment: @Bacco acontece o mesmo na wikipedia em inglês - você faz uma correção e ela é revertida. A cultura nos dois idiomas é a mesma - ilusão achar que a wiki em inglês é mais correta ou mais segura. Em inglês gealmente tem mais conteúdo, mas tem muita tosquice nos dois idiomas.

Comment: C# assim como Java é uma linguagem compilada e necessita de um compilador pra rodar seu programa

Comment: C# assim como Java é uma linguagem interpretada, onde ao compilar (realizar a build) é gerado um código fonte intermediário que será interpretado pela máquina virtual da linguagem. Este código fonte intermediário possui compiladores embutidos que, em tempo de execução, transformam o código intermediário em linguagem da máquina.
EDIT- ok, li a resposta marcada como melhor resposta e percebi minha falha no comentário acima.

Comment: Eu vejo em algumas fontes também comentarem sobre um terceiro tipo de linguagem, as híbridas. Quais as vantagens e desvantagens como também diferença entre as atuais.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ela é completamente compilada. Primeiro para um código intermediário, depois para código nativo.

Bom, essa é a explicação simples.

Nenhuma [linguagem de programação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102452/101) é compilada ou interpretada. [Linguagem é algo abstrato](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124436/101). [Assim como Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22647/101), C# normalmente é usada de forma compilada. Mas isso é um detalhe de implementação, nada exige que seja assim.

Isso [pode ser observado também no JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/26127/101), onde todos pensam ser interpretado (e não está totalmente errado).

Na verdade C# pode ser usada de forma interpretada (em geral as pessoas não usam a não ser como [REPL interativo](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Interactive-Window) ([veja mais](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/C%23-Interactive-Walkthrough)).

O que faz as pessoas acharem que C# é interpretada é que ela não costuma gerar o código nativo direto do jeito padrão de usar. Isso é feito por um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation)) em um segundo momento. O JITter é um compilador que gera código de máquina na hora de executar. No caso da plataforma .NET é feito em cima de um código intermediário mais simples de "interpretar". Mas não se engane, após passar pelo JITTer, não há interpretação.

[O normal é o .NET rodar em uma máquina virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118694/101), um [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). Ele é um mecanismo que controla toda execução da aplicação. Algumas [máquinas virtuais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/28097/101) são interpretadas. Não é o caso do C#. Ele pega o código intermediário (*bytecode*) produzido pelo compilador principal do C# e transforma em código de máquina na memória. Isso é feito uma vez na execução e depois usa o código igual seria no [C, C++, Pascal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7740/101), etc.

Há uma ferramenta chamada [`Ngen`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que faz essa compilação e gera um executável nativo para uso direto sem passar pelo JITter. Isso é feito após a instalação do aplicativo .NET, assim ganha tempo na carga do executável. Pode haver outros tipos de ganho, mas pode ter algumas perdas porque o código deixa de ficar adaptativo, na não ser que use um [otimizador global baseado em estatísticas de execução](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mpgo-exe-managed-profile-guided-optimization-tool?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Nas versões mais recentes do .NET Core esta forma foi ampliada e integrada na construção normal da aplicação. E mais recentemente ainda a capacidade de gerar algo AOT foi ampliada.

Mas nada impede que o código seja nativo desde o princípio. O [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) implementa C# de forma nativa, principalmente no [Android e iOS](https://www.xamarin.com/) que exigem isso. Já existe o [.NET Native](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/30793/101). E várias outras implementações de código nativo estão sendo desenvolvidas para o [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) ([LLILC](https://www.dotnetfoundation.org/blog/announcing-llilc-llvm-for-dotnet), [IL2CPP](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2014/05/20/the-future-of-scripting-in-unity/), entre outros). Isso está um pouco defasado, o .NET padrão já tem capacidade AOT.

Mas não se engane, esse código que não é inicialmente nativo nada tem a ver com interpretação.

## Interpretação

Outro detalhe importante é que [toda interpretação, no fundo passa por um processo de compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/77070/101). A diferença é que o interpretador já executa o código que encontrou e o compilador normal gera um código transformado que será executado posteriormente. Então o conceito de interpretação precisa ser bem entendido. O problema da interpretação é ficar fazendo a análise do código fonte o tempo todo.

Na verdade linguagens puramente interpretadas quase não existem mais, pelo menos entre as *mainstream*. O mais comum é ter pelo menos uma compilação para um código intermediário. O que costumamos dizer que é interpretado é quando o fonte sempre é necessário para executar. Mas essa definição é muito complicada de fazer. JS, por exemplo é interpretado no sentido que tem que analisar o código todo em cada execução. Mas é executado nativo porque após essa interpretação ele roda nativo. Pelo menos é assim nas implementações mais conhecidas.

Note que praticamente 100% das linguagens com implementação interpretada são dinâmicas em sua tipagem e até forma de execução. Muitas vezes isso traz um peso maior até que a interpretação.

Foi criado o .NET Native que gera código nativo de forma direta e dispensa o JITter. E mais recentemente começou esforços para que o .NET padrão também consiga gerar código nativo direto (Agora já funciona e está ótimo e chama [Native AOT](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/568799/101) e tem várias vantagens), até porque o .NET Native anterior foi abandonado (tem gente da comunidade que ainda tenta mantê-lo). Ao mesmo tempo que hoje o .NET gera WebAssembly que é algo totalmente diferente de tudo isso que falei.

Ou seja, vai ficando tudo mais complicado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Dei +1 e aguardo os detalhes.

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta!

Answer (score 7):

C# têm seus códigos fontes transformados em uma linguagem intermediária (específica de cada linguagem), que será interpretada pela máquina virtual da linguagem quando o programa for executado.
a partir dai podemos dizer que ela é uma linguagem interpretada.

Comment: Dá uma lida na minha resposta e siga os *links* para entender melhor o que é uma linguagem interpretada. C# não é interpretada.

Answer (score 6):

Cuidado ao comparar Asp.net com C# o asp.net também é compilado mas tem uma forma de rodar interpretado como projetos do tipo web site e não web application.

"Essencialmente, todas as linguagens .NET (incluindo Visual Basic, C#) são compiladas em código IL idênticos IL. Para ASP .NET esta primeira etapa de compilação pode acontecer automaticamente quando a página for solicitada pela primeira vez, ou você pode executá-la com antecedência (um processo conhecido como pré-compilação). O arquivo compilado com código IL é um chamado assembly."

Aqui está uma das grande magicas do .net framework que é a possibilidade de programar na linguagem que mais lhe convém compilar para um código que é interpretado pelo computador sem precisar modificar ou adaptar seu código.

Lembrando que você pode consumir pelo C# componentes feitos em Vb.Net, J#, Cobol.Net e etc. E todas essas linguagens consumir componentes construídos em C#.

Bons estudos.