# Linguagens de programação tipadas e não tipadas

Tags: característica-linguagem, tipagem

Qual o motivo (eu não sei se é uma regra) de linguagens de programação interpretadas (Ex.: PHP) não serem tipadas e as compiladas (Ex.: C) serem tipadas? (Java no caso é um híbrido).

Por que elas tem essas diferenças?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Tipagem

Em essência todas linguagens de programação são tipadas, ou seja, todos os dados são tipados, e concretamente o computador precisa ter um tipo, mesmo que seja único.

## Dinâmico X estático

Estritamente falando existem linguagens com tipagem dinâmica e com tipagem estática. As de tipagem dinâmica é dito que as variáveis possuem apenas um tipo e os dados possuem uma *tag* de tipo junto. Então a variável pode ter uma *tag* diferente dependendo do dado guardado nela. Falando mais informalmente podemos dizer que a variável tem um tipo diferente de acordo com o dado guardado.

O dado (o objeto) em si sempre tem seu próprio tipo. O que se fala em tipagem dinâmica tem a ver com a [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) apenas.

Claro que tipagem estática dá mais robustez e performance ao código já que não tem que ficar verificando em tempo de execução sobre tipos, então compilação encaixa bem nisso, afinal os principais pontos que a compilação dá é robustez e performance. É estranho uma linguagem rodando de forma interpretada querer ter uma tipagem robusta e que dê performance, assim como uma compilada que abra mão disso.

Por "tipada" você quer dizer que a variável tem seu tipo estático. Podemos combinar assim?

Boa parte do que quer saber já consta em [Qual a diferença entre uma linguagem de programação estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

Algumas linguagens com tipagem dinâmica estão adotando a explicitação do tipo de variáveis. Ajuda um pouco na robustez se o compilador souber lidar bem com isso, assim erros podem ser detectados mais facilmente. Claro, se a linguagem é interpretada ajuda pouco, mas ajuda, se você fizer muito teste. Se for compilada já detecta antes.

Essa nova forma costuma ser chamada de *type hint*, porque você não faz a variável ter apenas um tipo durante toda sua existência, apenas diz que é o tipo a ser considerado, portanto não melhora a performance, mas facilita a escala de desenvolvimento.

Tipagem dinâmica é flexível e ajuda desenvolver mais rápido (muito pouco, e se for bem testado, demora até mais, tem estudos que mostram isso), então essa forma de tipagem deveria ser usada apenas em pequena escala, para *scripts*, não para aplicações.

Como linguagens como PHP, Python, Ruby e até JavaScript começaram ser usadas em aplicações, ou os autores deveriam dizer para não fazerem isso, ou abraçar esse novo público e adotar o tipo explícito onde dá e foi o que elas começaram fazer, até JS através de TypeScript.

Mas não se engane, ainda mantém-se a tipagem dinâmica, tudo é resolvido em tempo de execução.

No fundo praticamente todas implementações de tipagem dinâmica fazem uso de uma `union` *taggeada* em C, algo assim:

```
struct data {
    int type;
    union data {
        int integer;
        double real;
        char * string;
        void * array;
        ...
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/DynamicType.c).

O *runtime* da linguagem então nunca acessa o dado diretamente, ele verifica o que está dentro disso e decide o que fazer durante a execução de acordo com o que está marcado em `type`

> Por que elas tem essas diferenças?

Pela comodidade que cada um dá.

Como já dito a tipagem estática dá mais robustez e performance, e facilita trabalhar com aplicações grandes.

A tipagem dinâmica tira um pouco da cerimônia de ter que dizer o tipo e permite uma variável ser reaproveitada para várias coisas (o que é questionável), o que dá um ganho inicial no tempo de desenvolvimento e se for um código *throw away*, esse ganho é importante. Se o código sobreviver mais aí ele começa jogar contra.

Em alguns cenários é preferível a flexibilidade e simplicidade do que a robustez e performance.

Assim tem ferramentas diferentes para cada caso. É por isso que tem chave de fenda e phillips.

## Premissas erradas na pergunta e em respostas

Há um erro na premissa da pergunta em achar que PHP é interpretada ou C é compilada. Existe PHP compilado e C interpretado. E não há qualquer relação entre tipagem e a maneira como o código é executado.

Java não tem nada de híbrido, ela é compilada. [Assim como C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125588/101). Claro que pode ter implementações interpretadas, mas o padrão não é assim e em qualquer linguagem pode ter ambos.

As linguagens típicas de *script* costumam ser compiladas, ao contrário da crença popular. PHP é a única das mais conhecidas que isso é mais limitado, mas ainda assim é compilada em cada execução (e vai mudar mais em PHP 8). Interpretação é um processo mais interativo e quase abandonado a não ser quando a execução precisa ser interativa mesmo.

PHP sempre teve tipagem em todos os dados. E em PHP 7 continua sendo assim, agora ele pode dar uma ajudinha quando você explicita o tipo, mas não mudou o sistema de tipagem.

Acho que PHP e JS são as únicas que podemos chamar de híbrida porque ela compila e executa todas vezes (JS há muito tempo é e PHP 8 é [JITtado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101)). Pelo menos é assim na forma como costumamos usar. As outras são compiladas para um *bytecode*, então não há interpretação. Não há execução direta de um código binário, mas isso é diferente de interpretação.

Até Lua que as pessoas esquecem como linguagem desse tipo é assim. E nem estou falando de LuaJIT que é até mais interpretada e aí sim pode ser considerada híbrida. E LuaJIT bate performance de todas essas mais conhecidas, além de ser mais simples. Chega competir com linguagens como C em alguns cenários.

C não tem nada de híbrido na sua forma normal, nem mesmo usando Clang. O que existe é uma separação clara entre a parte de compilação no *frontend* e no *backend* do compilador, igual acontece em praticamente todo compilador moderno, incluindo GCC, MSVC.

Alguns consideram que Java e C# são híbridas porque o código nativo só é gerado na execução, mas a compilação em si já ocorreu, só tem um passo extra, um *backend*, e isso está longe de ser interpretação, em qualquer definição disso.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, muito esclarecedor! Realmente tive que reconsiderar meu conceito a acerca do Java.

Comment: Agora que o verdadeiro autor se pronunciou +1 :)

Answer (score 13):

Na verdade, não é uma regra. Você certamente vai achar exceções dos dois lados.
O que acontece mais é um erro de classificação sobre o que é interpretado e o que é compilado: essa linha certamente era mais preto no branco na época que computadors tinham 64KB de memória no total.

Outra definição importante que está incorreta na pergunta - "não tipado" é diferente de "tipagem dinâmica" - shell script talvez possa ser chamado de "não tipado" (tudo é uma string, e cada comando/programa interpreta essas strings de uma forma, dependendo da posição, se correspondem a uma tag de opção, etc...) - mas linguagens como Javascript, Python Ruby, PHP tem tipos sim - só que o tipo é determinado em tempo de execução - isso é "dinamicamente tipado" - as que tem o tipo determinado em tempo de compilação e que não pode ser mudado, são "estaticamente tipadas" (e nem sempre é necessário que o tipo seja explicito na declaração de uma variável - o compilador pode inferir o tipo a partir do conteúdo declarado, por exemplo).

Mas, além do Java que você citou, o Python também é "compilado para uma máquina virtual que tem o bytecode interpretados". Ou seja, ambos são "híbridos", mas pelo fato do Java ser estaticamente tipado e Python ser dinamicamente tipado, é bem comum as pessoas dizerem que "Python é interpretado", enquanto que ninguém diz isso de Java.  Ou seja: há uma relação quase inversa - as pessoas assumem que Python é interpretado só por que tem tipagem dinâmica. O próprio C funciona dessa forma "híbrida" se você usar o compilador Clang, que compila pra LLVM - um máquina virtual bastante otimizada semelhante a do Python e a do Java, em vez de código nativo.

Mas, sim - tem fundamento essa percepção que você tem - e o motivo de mais linguagens compiladas terem tipagem estática é justamente que o _espaço_de_memória_ reservado para manter as variáveis é criado em tempo de compilação. Para manero exemplo em C, se o compilador "vê" uma variável do tipo "char", seguida de um "int" declaradas, sabe que vai precisar de 1 byte para uma e 4 (em geral) bytes para a outra - e já deixa um espaço de 5 bytes na área de endereçamento apropriada.

Ou seja - num programa em C, tudo o que se relaciona com o tamanho de uma variável, as instruções de máquina para escrever e ler seus valores, etc... são resolvidos no tempo de compilação - (inclusive `sizeof` não é uma função, mas uma instrução especial para o compilador). O código do programa enquanto está sendo executado não sabe nada sobe o tipo das variáveis, nem seus nomes. (apesar de que a imensa maioria dos programas é compilada com informação de depuração embutida, então esses metadados estão presentes, sim, nos arquivos binários).

Já, o requisito básico para uma linguagem de tipagem dinâmica é que o próprio conteúdo da variável tenha informação sobre seu tamanho em memória, e como pode ser usada. Em Python por exemplo, todas os tipos derivam de "object", que em seu layout na memória tem nos primeiros bytes um cabeçalho - e um dos campos desse cabeçalho é justamente o tamanho total do objeto na memória.

Outras linguagens vão usar estratégias diferentes - mas em geral, internamente, vão passar um endereço de memoria (o que em C seria um ponteiro) cada vez que uma variável for passada como parâmetro - e se, a qualquer momento durante a execução, for feita uma operação incompatível com o tipo de dado naquele endereço, ocorre um erro de execução (runtime error). Se a linguagem não tiver proteção para esse tipo de acesso, pode ser uma segmentation fault, e o processo é terminado. Senão, é lançada uma exceção dentro das próprias regras da linguagem que pode ser capturada - acntece com Python e Postscript, por exemplo.

Answer (score 8):

A tipagem em si é uma característica de cada linguagem sendo ela compilada ou não. Um bom exemplo é o próprio PHP.

A partir do php 5 ele possuía 2 tipos de tipagens (arrays e objetos com nome de classes). Já com o php 7 ele passa a ter outros tipos para tipagem que apesar de opcional não deixa de ser uma tipagem.

Comment: Poderia falar mais sobre essa "não tipagem" das versões anteriores ao PHP 7 e o que exatamente mudou na versão 7? Até onde sei, a única mudança que teve em relação a isso foi permitir o *type hint*, mas isso não tem relação alguma com ser tipagem estática ou dinâmica.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss então, no php 5 tem a introdução a tipagem mesmo que sendo só para Arrays e objetos com o nome da classe. Porém o intuito da minha resposta foi dizer que não é uma regra e que a tipagem em sí é uma característica de cada linguagem.

Comment: Mas isso é *type hint*, não tem relação com ser estático ou dinâmico.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss você tem razão, eu removi a referência da resposta.